# Is there any way to uninstall a cluster library for a single notebook in Databricks?

Tags: databricks

I have a library installed as a cluster library, so that it's available for all notebooks and everyone working on the cluster. However, for a specific use case (notebook), I need to uninstall that library, since it conflicts with another one.

Is there any way to do this locally, avoiding uninstalling it for the whole cluster?